# Realm: Query for objects with same property

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible in realm to query for objects that have the same property value?

Imagine a list of contacts with firstname and lastname. I want to query all contacts that have the same name and may be duplicates in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no automatic way to do that with `NSPredicate` (Of which Realm implements); it would need to be done manually.

That being said, it should be relatively trivial to do manually; simply loop through each object, performing a query that searches for that object's name properties, and see if the number of results returned is greater than 1.

That being said, depending on how big your data set is, this could become a very slow operation very quickly. Ideally, you might be better off ensuring that duplicate entries don't occur, or if they do, to somehow index them so they're easier to look up.

Comment: My hope was that Realm would have an better approach for this. I think I will store the names within an dictionary and do the comparison here instead of with thousands of Realm queries.